# Python3 - Methods of Landmark class? Landmark.getType listed in documentation, but doesn't work

Tags: google-api, python-3.7, google-vision

I'm trying to understand the Google Vision API, and am playing around with some python code. When I try to extract the type of a landmark, I can't find the right method.

The best [documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/vision/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/vision/v1/model/Landmark.html) I can find is for Java, where getType() is listed as a method.

Here is trial code with output:

```
from google.cloud import vision
import pickle
import inspect

client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

response = client.annotate_image({ 
    'image': {'source': {'image_uri': 'gs://bsa-test-bucket/2020-04-28 19.54.21.jpg'}},
    'features': [{'type': vision.enums.Feature.Type.FACE_DETECTION}, 
                {'type' : vision.enums.Feature.Type.LABEL_DETECTION}],})


for face in response.face_annotations:

    for i, lm in enumerate(face.landmarks):
        print(i, 'landmark_annotations type', type(lm), '\n')
        print(inspect.getmembers(lm))
        print(lm.getType())
```

Output:

```
> 0 landmark_annotations type <class
> 'google.cloud.vision_v1.proto.image_annotator_pb2.Landmark'> 
> 
> [('_SetListener', <bound method Message._SetListener of type: LEFT_EYE
> position {   x: 1198.06494140625   y: 1629.644287109375   z:
> -0.0032958984375 }
> >), ('__getstate__', <bound method Message.__getstate__ of type: LEFT_EYE position {   x: 1198.06494140625   y: 1629.644287109375   z:
> -0.0032958984375 }
> >)] 

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "src/gv-test.py", line 18, in <module>
    >     print(lm.getType()) AttributeError: getType
```

What is the correct method, and where can I find documentation for classes implemented in Python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found it. It is an attribute.

`response.face_annotations[0].type`

returns the correct type constant.